# How can I see the coordinates of my vanilla DJI Mavic while flying?

Tags: software, dji, dji-mavic-pro-1

What is the best way to get an older software version DJI Mavic to display GPS coordinates using the iPad?  What about a new one?  Is there a difference? If I can use something like Litchi to fly the coordinates that would be great, but without needing a firmware update would be best.  I do not want to install an app on my dedicated Mavic iPad that will force me to do a firmware update.

Comment: Suggest mavic-pro-1 or dji-mavic-pro as tag addition.

Comment: I found some info explaining to take a photo, download it, then view the metadata location info.  This isn't really real time, but it is a start.